# How to get weekly data from Foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I have a client that has a business (gym) and he wants to know who checked-in on that location the most weekly on Foursquare so he can give weekly prizes for the user with most check-ins.

I claimed the location on Foursquare but I can't get to that info.

I can see who were the *recent users* and *top users* who checked-in. And if I request an email report for a specific week, I see only for every day how many users checked-in, but not  who checked-in.

Is there a way to get to that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Venue timeseries](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/timeseries) data from the [Foursquare Merchant API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants) is used for the weekly email summaries which (as you note) only gives aggregate information about visitors (e.g. `uniqueVisitors` over a given week).

A venue manager is able to get the data for top users over a given period of time through the [Venue Stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats)

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/stats
```

In addition to the `VENUE_ID` parameter you can also give `startAt` and `endAt` parameters to get the week you want.

The [Venue Stats Response](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venuestats) field will include `topVisitors`:

> An array of the top 10 users by check-in count during the time period.
>   Array elements are objects with fields user, a compact user, and
>   checkins, the number of checkins by that user. Does not include users
>   who have opted out of sharing their check-ins with venue managers in
>   their settings.

This way you will be able to see/identify the top users for that week *by check-in count* .